# Google Charts overflow with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics, google-visualization

I have been working on a dashboard using Bootstrap and Google Charts.  I have a problem where the charts overflow.  I first noticed the problem on pages where all the content doesn't fit on the screen and the vertical scroll bar appears.  After the page loads, if I re-size the browser window, then the charts re-draw and everything looks good.  How can I work around this issue?

[image: Bootstrap Googlechart responsive dashboard]

I have included a sample of the code with the area chart that appears in the picture:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Site1.com Analytics</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Load the Visualization API and the chart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_google_user_count);

            function drawChart_google_user_count() {
                var json = $.ajax({
                    url: 'google_analytics_user_count_data.php', // make this url point to the data file
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false
                }).responseText;

                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
                var options = {
                                        height: 300,
                                        chartArea: {width: '98%', height: '80%'},
                                        hAxis:  {showTextEvery: 7, textStyle: {fontSize: '10'}},
                                        legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 12}},
                                        lineWidth: 4,
                                        pointShape: 'circle',
                                        pointSize: 6,
                                        vAxis: {textPosition: 'in', gridlines: {count: 3}, minorGridlines: {count: 2}, textStyle: {fontSize: 12}},
                };
                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                //do not forget to check ur div ID
                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_google_user_count'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

                        $(window).resize(function(){
                            drawChart_google_user_count();
                        })                                  
           </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class = "row voffsetpercent">
                <div class = "col-md-12">
                    <div class = "chart-title">Visitors Per Day</div>
                    <div id="chart_div_google_user_count"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I set a height in px on each of the div tags containing a chart like so:

```
<div id="chart_div_google_user_count" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

This seems to clear up the chart from overflowing the div on initial loading of the page.